# Custom date format in Quicksight

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I am trying to specify a custom date format in a quicksight dataset column which looks like this:

`2023-07-14T19:33:48.334Z`

however I get an error message when I input what I believe to be the correct date format i.e.

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:SSSZ
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ
```

results in

```
We encountered an error trying to validate the date format. Please try again.
```

what is the proper format to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This format turned out to work:

```
yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ
```